# To hide div in component if there is no JSON data

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an component called `details` which is an `child` component, Which will display the selected object properties from the other child component called `list` as in the below image:

[image]

**details.component.html**

```
<div classs="details-sec">
 <h3>Customer Details </h3>
  <div>Name : {{contact?.name}}</div>
  <div>Age : {{contact?.age}}</div>
</div>
```

**details.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
export class DetailsComponent {
  @Input()
  public contact;

}
```

**Expected Result:** If the `list` component  doesn't have any data to emit,

- Then in `details` components it should hide `details-sec` (i,e name,age)
- Should display some text.

Something like this:

[image]

Tried this [question](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-cfdeb6?file=app/customer/customer.component.ts), it didn't worked for me.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-cfdeb6?file=app/customer/customer.component.ts)**

Comment: The demo link and the question link both point to the same url

Comment: could you show how other components where you are using `DetailsComponent`?

Comment: Hi, is your problem resolved or still you need help?

Comment: I got the solution.@dileepkumarjami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check for `contact` property to show the details, else show a different template with the needed message.

Example:

**details.component.html**

```html
<div classs="details-sec" *ngIf="contact; else noDetails">
 <h3>Customer Details </h3>
  <div>Name : {{contact?.name}}</div>
  <div>Age : {{contact?.age}}</div>
</div>

<ng-template #noDetails>
    <div>
        <p>No customer available... </p>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add an `Input` value to your component, for example `hasCustomers` which should be set in parent if there are any Customers on list.

Then just use `*ngIf="hasCustomers"` and display text which you want.

The html file should be like this:

```
<div classs="details-sec" *ngIf="hasCustomers">
 <h3>Customer Details </h3>
  <div>Name : {{contact?.name}}</div>
  <div>Age : {{contact?.age}}</div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!hasCustomers">
  No customer are available
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do ngIf in angular go see this link.

[https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf][1]

[1]: Angular Ngif